# MySQL: week date range from week number in a query

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I got a database table that looks something like this:

```
| id         | clock         | info
----------------------------------------------
| 1          | 1262556754    | some info
| 2          | 1262556230    | some other info
| 3          | 1262556988    | and another
| 4          | 1262555678    | and some more
```

It contains log records and a unix timestamp, when this log was written. What I need, is to get a weekly report, on how many log records there was during each week. Here is a query that I wrote:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(clock), "%U") AS week
count(*) as cnt
FROM logs
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(clock), "%Y") = '2010'
GROUP BY week
```

This gives a result like this:

```
| week       | cnt
-------------------------------
| 1           | 55 
| 2           | 134   
| 4           | 765
| 20          | 65
```

Great! But what I would like to see, is a date ranges like `08 Feb 2010 00:00 - 15 Feb 2010 00:00`, so my result set would look like this:

```
| day_start           | day_end           | cnt
---------------------------------------------------------
| 08 Feb 2010 00:00   | 15 Feb 2010 00:00 | 55 
| 15 Feb 2010 00:00   | 22 Feb 2010 00:00 | 76
| 22 Feb 2010 00:00   | 01 Mar 2010 00:00 | 756
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: That approach isn't going to work terribly well if you've got data from different years in the same table - `%U` gives the week number (where Sunday is the first day of the week) - the first Sunday in 2009 would be 1, just like the first Sunday in 2010. You might need a different approach. Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fyearweek

Comment: My reports are year specific, I edited the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `STR_TO_DATE('201008 Monday', '%X%V %W');` to get a proper date like `2010-02-22` then use `DATE_FORMAT` to get the format you need.

Answer (score 3):

If that "week" column stores the number of a given week within a year, you could simply convert it to a date string using the makedate function.

E.g:

```
select makedate(2010, week * 7);
```

It should work, given that your reports are year-specific.
Cheers

Comment: I have some data , in that we have a column load_date. Now I want to convert date into week. Say load_date is from **2013-01-01 to 2013-01-07**.  It should return it as week1.and from **2013-01-08 to 2013-01-15**. It should return result as week2

Answer (score 0):

I would simply select your `day_start` and then group by that.

If you consider Sunday the first day of the week, subtract `DAYOFWEEK() - 1` to get the most recent Sunday.  Then add 6 days to get the following Saturday.  And that's you date range:

```
SELECT
  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(clock) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(clock)) - 1 DAY) AS day_start,
  (SELECT day_start) + INTERVAL 6 DAY AS day_end
  COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM logs
GROUP BY day_start
```